# Wanting to change a setter of a single input field, how to advance to check if those were changed before and how not to lose the previous addages?

Tags: javascript, getter, setter, defineproperty, propertydescriptor

This is a follow up question to [Setter for HTMLInputElement.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320686/setter-for-htmlinputelement-value/55993131#55993131).

If I changed the setter and getter of a single input-element (not on all input elements in general), and later on I want to make another change (for example done by a third party javascript-module) to this specific input element, how would the second changing work, so that it doesn't override the first change of getter and setter but would just add it sown change?

Specifically or in general: When changing the setter and getter how could the second changing javascript code establish what to change and how to change it without losing the previous addage?

**Edit:** After the following code, what if I (or a third party module) wants to "inject" a second, a "doSomeLogicWithInput2"-function, into exactly the same input-setter (or getter) with the id "anInputElement"?

```
    function doSomeLogicWithInput(input) {
        if (input.value.toLowerCase()==='one') {input.style.color='black'; } else { input.style.color='red';} 
    }   
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('anInputElement');

    Object.defineProperty(inputElement, 'value', {
        // HTMLInputElement is like inputElement.prototype.Symbol ???
        set: function(newValue) {
            var valueProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
            var valuePropResult = valueProp.set.call(inputElement, newValue);
            doSomeLogicWithInput(inputElement);
            return valuePropResult;
        },
        get : function() {
            var valueProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
            return valueProp.get.call(inputElement);
        }
    });
    
            
    // Catch end-user changes
    inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(event) { doSomeLogicWithInput(event.target); }, true);
```

**Edit 2:**
This is an example how I tried to use Bergi's functions, but it doesn't work really. In the function logic `el.value` returns `'undefined'`.

```
<html><head>
<script>

function getAccessorDescriptor(obj, prop) {
  if (obj == null) { // only necessary if you may overwrite missing properties
    return {
      get(){},
      set(){},
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true
    };
  }
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
  if (!desc) {
    return getAccessorDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), prop);
  }
  if ("writable" in desc) { // only necessary if you might overwrite data properties
    return {
      get() { return desc.value; },
      set(v) { if (desc.writable) desc.value = v; else throw new TypeError() },
      enumerable: desc.enumerable,
      configurable: true,
    }
  }
  return desc;
}

function addSetLogic(obj, prop, logic) {
  const oldDescriptor = getAccessorDescriptor();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
    ...oldDescriptor,
    set(value) {
      oldDescriptor.set.call(this, value);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      logic(this, value);
    }
  });
}


var elem; 
function runtest() {
    elem = document.getElementById('mycolor');
    addSetLogic(elem, 'value', logic);
    elem.value='bar';
}
function logic(el,newValue) {
    console.log(el,el.value);  // <- el.value is undefined
    if (el.value==='standard') { el.style.color='black;'}
    else { el.style.color='red'; }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="runtest();">
<input id="mycolor" type="text" value="foo">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you want by "make another change" - maybe show some code? It's not so clear

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added the code I use so far, but I really must admit, that I have not the slightest clue how to do what I ask for. That's why I have no code I tried. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value')` every time you access the property, and also don't get it from `HTMLInputElement.prototype` but rather from the `inputElement` itself if there already is one. Rather use the one you have replaced/overwitten with the new descriptor:

```
function getAccessorDescriptor(obj, prop) {
  if (obj === null) { // only necessary if you may overwrite missing properties
    return {
      get(){},
      set(){},
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true
    };
  }
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
  if (!desc) {
    return getAccessorDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), prop);
  }
  if ("writable" in desc) { // only necessary if you might overwrite data properties
    return {
      get() { return desc.value; },
      set(v) { if (desc.writable) desc.value = v; else throw new TypeError() },
      enumerable: desc.enumerable,
      configurable: true,
    }
  }
  return desc;
}

function addSetLogic(obj, prop, logic) {
  const oldDescriptor = getAccessorDescriptor(obj, prop);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
    ...oldDescriptor,
    set(newValue) {
      oldDescriptor.set.call(this, newValue);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      logic(this, newValue);
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can do

```
addSetLogic(inputElement, 'value', doSomeLogicWithInput);
addSetLogic(inputElement, 'value', doSomeLogicWithInput2);
```

as often as you want.

Comment: That solves basically all the questions I had about the other question I linked and its answer. Especially `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` and `...oldDescriptor` and the helper function `getAccessorDescriptor` is what I wished to do, but would never have been able to solve. I will try it tomorrow! TY!!

Comment: I tried this, but when in my `doSomeLogicWithInput` function I try to access the value (`[the this from the logic(this, newValue) call in your code].value`), it doesn't work. Based on one of the answers to the question I linked at the start I tried to add a get-part to your code, under the set:`get: function() {return oldDescriptor.get.call(this); /*return this.getPropertyValue(prop);*/} `, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work, replacing `logic(this, newValue)` with `something(this.value)`? Please provide a [mcve] of the code you're attempting to run, and the output you expect.

Comment: I edited my question, and added an example at "Edit 2". Merry Christmas!

Comment: I might add, that later on other parts all over my app access the value by `document.getElementById("mycolor").value`, and only getting `"undefined"`.

Comment: @Bill2022 Whoops, looks like I forgot to call `getAccessorDescriptor` properly!

Comment: It seems to work now. That's so great, ty! Have a great festive time!